# No matching call error for unordered_map

Tags: c++, dictionary

My line:

```
unordered_map < pair<long long,long long>, long long> myMap;
```

And the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::unordered_map<std::pair<long long int, long long int>, long long int>::unordered_map()'
```

Code that reproduces the error:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

unordered_map < pair<long long,long long>, long long> myMap;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you `#include <unordered_map>` and `#include <utility>`?

Comment: I included both, yes.

Comment: Please include a copy of a minimal working example of your code to help people better diagnose your problem

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: With another compiler, the message is "The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.". Meaning `std::pair`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) requires a hash functor in order to do anything. By default, that hash functor is is [`std::hash<Key>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) - but the standard only provides specializations for the integral types and pointers. `std::pair<long long, long long>` is neither, so effectively the compiler is telling you that you cannot instantiate the `unordered_map` you want because its hash functor is ill-formed.

What you need to do is provide your own. For example, here is the worst possible hash functor:

```
struct AlwaysZero {
    size_t operator()(pair<long long, long long> const& ) const {
        return 0;
    }
};

unordered_map < pair<long long,long long>, long long, AlwaysZero> myMap;
```

That compiles. It will also perform terribly. You could check out [`boost::hash_combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html) to get an idea of how to correctly write a much better hash.

Comment: It's possible that I am asking an XY question. Is there a better way to do a lookup by two variables? I'm basically trying to create a map where I feed it (a,b) and it returns c, and as efficiently as possible to minimize overall runtime.

Comment: I also find this strange because using pairs works with map but not unordered_map

Comment: @user64283 Having a `pair<a,b>` for the key sounds reasonable to me if that's what you're doing. Your problem is just that the standard library doesn't support that by default.

Comment: @user64283 Because `pair` has `operator<` defined as lexicographic comparison. What would the default `pair` hash functor be?

Comment: what about combining the two (separated by space) as a string as using that as a key instead?

Comment: Nvm, it performs worse than using regular map.

Comment: @user64283 That sounds terrible.

Comment: Can you explain why it is terrible?

Comment: @user64283 Because it's a hack. You want to look up `(a,b)` so look up `(a,b)`, don't look up `str(a) + " " + str(b)`. And doing math with numbers is muuuuch faster than doing math with strings. And you don't need to deal with memory allocation.